# PDF Output format from Latex/LuaTex

Tags: formatting, pdf

I have general questions about the PDF output format for a novel (text only), written using LaTex/LuaTex/Komascript(book):

Is it possible to obtain a PDF/A or PDF/X format? Or do I need to add code to the style file (the preamble) to obtain this format?

Many thanks

Comment: There's a brand new class [`novel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/novel) that has build in support for PDF/X.

Comment: Thank you - I am examining the new package. It looks as if this might be the answer I was hoping for. Again, many thanks.